# webpack.Compiler takes a lot of time, ng-serve

Tags: angular, webpack

When doing a ng serve --verbose I spotted an abnormal quantity of time spent by the webpack.Compiler during the make hook phase.
This happened after migrating Angular Material from 14 to 15 but I don't get how could I reduce this phase's execution time. Any ideas?

```
LOG from webpack.Compiler
<t> make hook: 571017.1161 ms
<t> finish make hook: 0.0854 ms
<t> finish compilation: 116.4237 ms
<t> seal compilation: 1475.5701 ms
<t> afterCompile hook: 0.3705 ms
<t> emitAssets: 789.1355 ms
<t> emitRecords: 0.227 ms
```

Comment: same, with make hook which takes a lot of time; without any migration, Angular 14